# Getting all functions/variables from `require` in Javascript (Mocha)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, blockchain, hardhat

So, I have a `utils.js` file that has many functions, say `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e`.

Every time I have to call those functions in any other javascript function, I have to do:

```
const {a, b, c, d, e} = require("./utils.js");
...
```

Is there a way like `*` something, which allows me to get all the functions at once, rather than getting all functions one by one?

Context:

- I am using this for testing my smart contracts in a blockchain project.
- Using hardhat for testing (which uses Mocha for test running).

Comment: You could do `const utils = require("./utils")` which would make all of the functions properties of `utils`. eg `utils.a()` `utils.b()`.

Comment: The devil on my shoulder wants to tell you that you could just do `with(require("/utils.js")) { ... }` -- but that is a horrible idea that (1) will destroy efficient identifier resolution (and guarantees of consistency about what variables exist moment to moment) and (2) might be out-and-out disabled in Node? I hope it is.

Comment: @lejlun Yes, that is a good way, except that I have asked this question at the end, so now making this change means changing every file these function it uses, so a very long process. But appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse names of all required funcs in **a**, then redefine them in global scope in the loop by a.x:

```
const a = require('./funcs.js') //contains lettergen(num), simple passgen
for(i in a){
    global[i] = a[i]; //magic
}
console.log(lettergen(15));
```

This is also devil's solution, but now I am also facing this, and in my specific situation it could be simpler than anything.